# realtime querying - HBase or Cassandra which is the best fit?

Tags: cassandra, hbase

we trying to build a data-ware house for our transaction system.
-  We make 5000 -6000 transaction per day, they can go > 20,000.
-  Each transaction produce a file, size (> 4MB)

we want to have a system, which can make updates to the existing data, consistent and availability, and have good read performance. Infrastructure is not any issue.

Hbase or cassandra or any other ? your help and guidance is highly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most of newer nosql platform can do what you need in terms of performance - both hbase and cassandra scales horizontally (also Aerospike and others) so performances can be guaranteed if the data-model respect the "product-patterns" for data distribution.

I would not choose the technology in terms of performances. 
What I would do is:

1. a list of different features offered by a bunch of products and then consider the one that, out of the box, best fit my needs
2. a list of operation I need to do on data and check if I am not going "*against*" some specific product

While 1 is easily done the 2 need a deep product analysis. For instance you say you need to update existing data -- let's imagine you choose Cassandra and you update very very frequently a column on which you put a secondary index (that, under the hood, creates a lookup table) for searching purpose. Any time you perform an update on this column on the lookup table a deletion and insertion is performed. You can read in this [article](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-anti-patterns-queues-and-queue-like-datasets) that performing many deletes in Cassandra is considered an anti-pattern and can lead to problematic situations. This is just an example I did on Cassandra because is the one I know best among nosql products and not to tell you avoid Cassandra.

Comment: Thanks Carlo! Do you have any idea on Hbase ? I heard if the file size we are storing in less than the hfds default size, there is a hit on the performance, is this true ?

Comment: I honestly have no idea but this is exactly what I mean when I say check for everything before choosing your product